# Reduce the loop logic?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to refactor this so the code look shorter and readable? There won't be more than 100 Ids in the `payload`, so I think the performance does not matter in this case.

```js
const payload = {
    RequestIds: [ 
        { Id: 1 },
        { Id: 3 },
    ]
}

const result = {
    Items: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 A'},
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 B'},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 C'},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 D'},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 E'},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 F'},
    ]
}


const items = [];
for(const payloadItem of payload.RequestIds) {
    const filteredItems = result.Items.filter(item => item.Id === payloadItem.Id);

    if (filteredItems.length > 0) {
        items.push(...filteredItems);
    }
}

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a Set of the `Id`s in the payload, then do a single `.filter` by whether the Id being iterated over is included:

```js
const payload = {
    RequestIds: [ 
        { Id: 1 },
        { Id: 3 },
    ]
};
const payloadIds = new Set(payload.RequestIds.map(({ Id }) => Id));

const result = {
    Items: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 A'},
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Item 1 B'},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 C'},
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Item 2 D'},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 E'},
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Item 3 F'},
    ]
}

const items = result.Items.filter(({ Id }) => payloadIds.has(Id));
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```js
const resultItems = result.Items;
const items = payload.RequestIds.reduce((prev, cur) => [...prev, ...resultItems.filter(item => item.Id === cur.Id)], []);
```

or

```js
const items = resultItems.filter(item => payload.RequestIds.some(req => req.Id === item.Id));
```